# Ffmpeg command results in output contains no video stream error

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to execute the following command:

`ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel warning -progress -i E:\TEMP\mtc\input\sample2.mp4 -acodec mp3 -vcodec libx265 -r 60 -vf "scale=2560:1440" -b:v 35000k -f matroska E:\TEMP\mtc\input\output\result.mkv`

This results in error:
Output file #0 does not contain any stream

The input file exists and can be accessed by ffmpeg.
I'm working on Windows 10 with latest version of FFmpeg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding - after -progress

`ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel warning -progress - -i E:\TEMP\mtc\input\sample2.mp4 -acodec mp3 -vcodec libx265 -r 60 -vf "scale=2560:1440" -b:v 35000k -f matroska "E:\TEMP\mtc\input\output\result.mkv"`